# Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen einer Sühne und einer Buße?

Tags: difference

> **Sühne:**
>     etwas, was jemand auf sich nimmt, was jemand tut, um ein begangenes Unrecht, eine Schuld zu sühnen (a); Buße
>
> **Buße:**
>
> 1. a. (Religion) das Bemühen um die Wiederherstellung eines durch menschliches Vergehen gestörten Verhältnisses zwischen Gott und Mensch
>
>    b. (katholische Kirche) Bußübung
> 2. Ausgleich, den jemand für eine geringfügige Rechtsverletzung zu zahlen hat

Quelle: Duden

Besteht vielleicht der Unterschied darin, dass die Sühne etwas ist, das wir aus dem Vorsatz tun, durch uns angerichteten Schaden zu ersetzen, und die Buße einfach ein Gebet ist, das wir sprechen müssen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Offiziell" kann ich leider keine Belege für unterschiedliche Bedeutungen finden - die beiden können also wohl weitgehend synonym verwendet werden.
Ich bin mir allerdings ziemlich sicher, dass gewisse Nuancen verschieden sind:

**Sühne** hat meines Erachtens eine größere Tragweite und einen fast zeremoniellen Charakter, insofern dass das Sühnen oft öffentlich passiert. Es muss sich nicht um eine an sich extrem drastische Aktion (irgendwie mit Blut oder so) handeln - aber die Implikation liegt eher im grandiosen, bombastischen Bereich. Vielleicht, weil eine Verfehlung, die man "sühnen" muss, eher eine größere ist. Sühne hat in der Regel symbolischen Charakter (evtl. weil die Verfehlung als so gravierend empfunden wird, dass sie gar nicht wieder gut gemacht oder jemand adäquat dafür entschädigt werden *kann*).

**Buße** scheint mir kleinkarierter zu sein. Das leistet man auch mal für kleinere Verfehlungen. "Bußgeld" ist was ziemlich Alltägliches - wohingegen *"Sühnegeld" eher nach dem alten "Wergeld" klingt.

Answer (score 1):

Generell würde ich sagen, daß Sühne immer vom Betroffenen selbst ausgeht. Im Gegensatz dazu kann man aber auch jemand anderen für etwas büßen lassen.

Comment: Der Ausdruck "jemanden für etwas büssen lassen" hat aber mit Busse nicht viel zu tun. Das ist mehr ein Euphemismus für "sich an jemandem rächen".

Comment: @PMF: Im Orient gab es das Zeremoniell des Sündenbocks. Dabei wurden einem Bock symbolisch die eigenen Sünden aufgehalst, und dann wurde er zum verdursten in die Wüste gejagd. Allerdings habe ich "Sühnebock" oder "Bußbock" noch nicht gehört, meine aber dass man umgekehrt Sühne für Untaten anderer (Vorfahren, Verwandte, ...) leisten kann.

Answer (score 1):

Meinem Verständnis nach gibt es keine wesentliche Unterschiede zwischen *Sühne* und *Buße* und genauso auch nicht zwischen *sühnen* und *büßen*. Auch der Wikipedia-Artikel über [Sühne](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%BChne) lässt keinen offensichtlichen Unterschied erkennen.

Laut Wiktionary besagen beide Wörter, dass eine Wiedergutmachung geleistet wird – wie auch immer diese aussieht. *Buße* bzw. *büßen* können darüberhinaus aber auch bedeuten, dass eine Strafe auf sich genommen wird (was nicht unbedingt mit Wiedergutmachung gleichgesetzt werden kann). Hier denke ich wird insbesondere Bezug auf die rechtliche Verwendung von *Buße* genommen. Dort wird meines Wissens *Sühne* gar nicht verwendet.

*Buße* ist allgemein häufiger verwendet als *Sühne*. Das gilt insbesondere für das Verb *büßen*. Mir persönlich ist das Wort *Sühne* sogar so fremd, dass ich beim ersten Lesen des Titels dachte, es wäre ein Tippfehler. Erst beim zweiten Lesen wurde mir bewusst, dass das Wort tatsächlich existiert.

Wer sich intensiv mit Religion und dem Thema der Buße beschäftigt, mag eventuell einen Unterschied zwischen *Sühne* und *Buße* verstehen; das kann ich aber nicht beurteilen und ist schlicht ins Blaue geraten.

Fazit: Kein Unterschied zwischen *Sühne* und *Buße*.

Comment: Aktion Sühnezeichen nie gehört? https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aktion_S%C3%BChnezeichen_Friedensdienste

Answer (score 0):

Sühne leistet jemand für die Fehler und Sünden eines anderen. Buße leistet derjenige, der diese Fehler und Sünden begangen hat. Beispiel: Jesus Christus hat die Sünden der Welt durch seinen Tod "gesühnt", viele Heilige der Kirche waren zuvor regelrechte Sünder und haben durch Umkehr und Buße auf den Weg der Heiligkeit zurückgefunden, der jedem Menschen offensteht.

Comment: Das ist mir nun doch eeeeeeetwas zu evangelikal angehaucht - selbst wenn die Frage sich sowieso schon mit Religion beschäftigt.

Comment: Leider fehlt hier komplett die Bedeutung von *Sühne* als "Rache"/"Vergeltung"/"Strafe", d.h. eine Form von aktiver *Gewaltausübung*, die einen noch stärkeren Gegensatz zur Buße herstellt (und die der Duden im Zitat des Fragers leider auch nicht erwähnt).

Comment: Nach nochmaligem Lesen der anderen Antworten komme ich aber zu dem Schluss, dass deine das Potential hat, den Punkt am genauesten zu treffen - +1

Answer (score -2):

Die beiden Wörter, Sühne und Busse(1) sind meinem Gefühl nach ziemlich verwandt.

> Er leistet Busse für seine Missetaten.
>   Er leistet Sühne für seine Missetaten.

Letzteres tönt altbacken. Das würde ich eher formulieren als

> Er sühnt für seine Missetaten.

Sühne würde ich, wenn überhaupt, nur in einem religiösen Kontext brauchen. Sonst tönt es in meinen Ohren veraltet.

NB: Dass Busse(2) eine sehr irdische Sache ist, braucht wahrscheinlich nicht betont zu werden.